# Adding dynamic fields in a form with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

Let's say that the entity `Foo` has many entities `Bar`.
In `views/Foo/new.html` I want to create many entities `Bar` in the same form, allowing to the user add many groups of HTML fields each time that the user clicks on a button "Add". When the user submits the form, I want to create all entities and the new `Foo` related with all `Bars`.

What is the best approach to do it in Symfony2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the embedded collection of forms. There is pretty good documentation about that at Symfony's website - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html